# reference object from string groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

how to reference an object from string in groovy? I have many objects - reviewSyd1, reviewSyd2..reviewSyd30 that i need to add to object - sydney. I have loop

```
for(i in 1..30){
  sydney.addToReviews("reviewSyd$i")
}
```

This is not working. how to make it work?

Thank You

Updated to clarify(sorry if i wasn't clear)

```
class Review{
   String email
   String Content

}

def rev1 = new Review(email:'one@homail.com',content:'i really like it')
def rev2 = new Review(email:'two@homail.com',content:'i really like it')
def rev3 = new Review(email:'three@homail.com',content:'i really like it')
def rev4 = new Review(email:'four@homail.com',content:'i really like it')

for(i in 1..4){
   println rev$i.email
}
```

How to reference the object -revX where x is the iterator?

Comment: You don't have references to these objects?

Comment: These objects are not in a collection? If they are in a script, they are accessible through the `binding` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
println rev$i.email
```

Not that dynamic is groovy. This not a valid groovy syntax.
Put those object, you want to access in later in your code,in a collection.

```
def revs = []
revs << new Review(email:'one@homail.com',content:'i really like it')
revs << new Review(email:'two@homail.com',content:'i really like it')
revs << new Review(email:'three@homail.com',content:'i really like it')
revs << new Review(email:'four@homail.com',content:'i really like it')
```

then you will have references to them:

```
revs.each{
   println it.email
}
```